# WordPress: How to link the name of an author to that author's list of posts

Tags: wordpress

I'm setting up a WordPress blog and I can't manage to link an author's name to the list of posts written by that author.

I am using this code:

```
written by <a href="<?php get_author_posts_url(); ?>"><?php the_author() ?></a>
```

But this gives me following error:

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for get_author_posts_url(), called in /customers/zinneket.be/zinneket.be/httpd.www/wp-content/themes/zinneket/index.php on line 15 and defined in /customers/zinneket.be/zinneket.be/httpd.www/wp-includes/author-template.php on line 220
```

Line 15 is of course the one copied above.

Does anyone know the right way to do this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_author_posts_url) makes it fairly clear that you need to provide an argument (to identify what author you're interested in).

From the looks of it, [the_author_posts_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_author_posts_link) is what you want to use.

Rule of thumb: `the_` functions involve the current author/post/page/whatever, `get_` functions require you to identify what author/post/page/whatever you are interested in.

Comment: Thank you very much, that works like a charm! And thanks for explaining the difference between `the_` and `get_` as well, I did not know that. Cheers!